# 'this' cannot be used in a constant expression error (C++) with this-> pointer variable

Tags: c++, error-handling

I am getting this error message and I know it's because the argument in the array must be constant, but I am not sure how to arrange my 'this-> V; to be constant. Any help? I provided mostly code so that the function of the pointer variable could be evident throughout the program.

```
// A class that represents an undirected graph
class Graph
{
int V;    // number of vertices
list<int> *adj;    // A dynamic array of adjacency lists
int *in;
public:
// Constructor and destructor
Graph(int V);
~Graph() { delete[] adj; delete[] in; }

// function to add an edge to graph
void addEdge(int v, int w) { adj[v].push_back(w);  (in[w])++; }

// Method to check if this graph is Eulerian or not
bool isEulerianCycle();

// Method to check if all non-zero degree vertices are connected
bool isSC();

// Function to do DFS starting from v. Used in isConnected();
void DFSUtil(int v, bool visited[]);

Graph getTranspose();
};

Graph::Graph(int V)
{
this->V = V;
adj = new list<int>[V];
in = new int[V];
for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
    in[i] = 0;
}

/* This function returns true if the directed graph has an eulerian
cycle, otherwise returns false  */
bool Graph::isEulerianCycle()
{
// Check if all non-zero degree vertices are connected
if (isSC() == false)
    return false;

// Check if in degree and out degree of every vertex is same
for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
    if (adj[i].size() != in[i])
        return false;

return true;
}

// A recursive function to do DFS starting from v
void Graph::DFSUtil(int v, bool visited[])
{
// Mark the current node as visited and print it
visited[v] = true;

// Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex
list<int>::iterator i;
for (i = adj[v].begin(); i != adj[v].end(); ++i)
    if (!visited[*i])
        DFSUtil(*i, visited);
}

// Function that returns reverse (or transpose) of this graph
// This function is needed in isSC()
Graph Graph::getTranspose()
{
Graph g(V);
for (int v = 0; v < V; v++)
{
    // Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex
    list<int>::iterator i;
    for (i = adj[v].begin(); i != adj[v].end(); ++i)
    {
        g.adj[*i].push_back(v);
        (g.in[v])++;
    }
}
return g;
}

// This function returns true if all non-zero degree vertices of 
// graph are strongly connected
bool Graph::isSC()
{
// Mark all the vertices as not visited (For first DFS)
bool visited[V]; // error: 'this' cannot be used in a constant expression
for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
    visited[i] = false;

// Find the first vertex with non-zero degree
int n;
for (n = 0; n < V; n++)
    if (adj[n].size() > 0)
        break;

// Do DFS traversal starting from first non zero degree vertex.
DFSUtil(n, visited);

// If DFS traversal doesn't visit all vertices, then return false.
for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
    if (adj[i].size() > 0 && visited[i] == false)
        return false;

// Create a reversed graph
Graph gr = getTranspose();

// Mark all the vertices as not visited (For second DFS)
for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
    visited[i] = false;

// Do DFS for reversed graph starting from first vertex.
// Staring Vertex must be same starting point of first DFS
gr.DFSUtil(n, visited);

// If all vertices are not visited in second DFS, then
// return false
for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
    if (adj[i].size() > 0 && visited[i] == false)
        return false;

return true;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Where exactly do you get that error in that code?

Comment: Apparently the code you've presented does not exemplify the problem you describe. However there is a problem with raw arrays. Just use use `std::vector` instead: it's simpler and safer, win win.

Comment: I guess the error is at `adj = new list<int>[V];`. @OP why combine std containers and C-style arrays? use std vectors and lists all the way. i.e.: `vector<list<int>> adj;`

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I get the error at: bool visited[V]; // error: 'this' cannot be used in a constant expression

Comment: @A.S.H I just thought it would be easier to access the elements in the array presented like this instead of a vector

Comment: @ferret7DD not at all believe me. It even much easier with vectors, and you wont need to care about newing and deleting stuff.

Comment: @A.S.H therefore I can replace 'in = new int[V];' with   'code'  'in = int[V];'

Comment: @ferret7DD I clarified it in my answer below.

Comment: **Hi. Please don't change a question fundamentally, or entirely remove the original question, after answers have been posted. You have done that three or four times, but that's not how SO is intended to work. SO is not a debugging service. Rolled back to the latest version containing the original question, namely version 1.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++ does not support arrays with non-constant size. (non-constant means things that are not known at compile time). Hence errors at the line:

```
bool visited[V];
```

Rewrite your code and stick to std containers (std::vector, std::list).

```
class Graph
{
    int V;    // number of vertices
    vector<list<int>> adj;    // A dynamic array of adjacency lists
    vector<int> in;
    // etc...
    // and you can access the elements just like a normal array (in[3] = 5, etc...)

Graph::Graph(int V)
{
    this->V = V;
    adj.Resize(V);
    in.Resize(V);
    // etc

vector<bool> visited(V);
```

Hopefully this should provide a good start to fix your code and get past the current error.

EDIT

```
class Graph
{
    vector<list<int>> adj;     // A dynamic array of adjacency lists
    vector<int> in;
public:
    Graph(int V);
    ~Graph() { }
    // function to add an edge to graph
    void addEdge(int v, int w) { adj[v].push_back(w);  (in[w])++; }
    // Method to check if this graph is Eulerian or not
    bool isEulerianCycle();
    // Method to check if all non-zero degree vertices are connected
    bool isSC();
    // Function to do DFS starting from v. Used in isConnected();
    void DFSUtil(int v, vector<bool>& visited);

    Graph getTranspose();
};

Graph::Graph(int V)
{
    adj.resize(V);
    in.resize(V, 0);
}

/* This function returns true if the directed graph has an eulerian
cycle, otherwise returns false  */
bool Graph::isEulerianCycle()
{
    // Check if all non-zero degree vertices are connected
    if (isSC() == false)
        return false;

    // Check if in degree and out degree of every vertex is same
    for (size_t i = 0; i < adj.size(); i++)
        if (adj[i].size() != in[i])
            return false;
    return true;
}

// A recursive function to do DFS starting from v
void Graph::DFSUtil(int v, vector<bool>& visited)
{
    // Mark the current node as visited and print it
    visited[v] = true;

    // Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex
    for (auto i = adj[v].begin(); i != adj[v].end(); ++i)
        if (!visited[*i])
            DFSUtil(*i, visited);
}




Graph Graph::getTranspose()
{
    Graph g(adj.size());
    for (int v = 0; v < adj.size(); v++)
    {
        // Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex
        //list<int>::iterator i;
        for (auto i = adj[v].begin(); i != adj[v].end(); ++i)
        {
            g.adj[*i].push_back(v);
            (g.in[v])++;
        }
    }
    return g;
}
// This function returns true if all non-zero degree vertices of 
// graph are strongly connected
bool Graph::isSC()
{
    // Mark all the vertices as not visited (For first DFS)
    vector<bool> visited(adj.size(), false);

    // Find the first vertex with non-zero degree
    int n;
    for (n = 0; n < adj.size(); n++)
        if (adj[n].size() > 0)
            break;

    // Do DFS traversal starting from first non zero degree vertex.
    DFSUtil(n, visited);

    // If DFS traversal doesn't visit all vertices, then return false.
    for (int i = 0; i < adj.size(); i++)
        if (adj[i].size() > 0 && visited[i] == false)
            return false;

    // Create a reversed graph
    Graph gr = getTranspose();

    // Mark all the vertices as not visited (For second DFS)
    visited.resize(visited.size(), false);

    // Do DFS for reversed graph starting from first vertex.
    // Staring Vertex must be same starting point of first DFS
    gr.DFSUtil(n, visited);

    // If all vertices are not visited in second DFS, then
    // return false
    for (int i = 0; i < adj.size(); i++)
        if (adj[i].size() > 0 && visited[i] == false)
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: You're on to something, absolutely, sort of **in the right direction**, but I don't think there is any error at `new int[V]`.

Comment: Yes. C++ fully supports dynamic allocation of dynamic size raw arrays. You just can't declare a dynamic size raw array as a variable.

Comment: ah yes you are right. the error is what I think but at another place. I will edit. @Cheersandhth.-Alf

Comment: @A.S.H so I can delete my destructors then since I do not need to use 'delete' anymore

Comment: @ferret7DD If you stick to std containers, you will need no `new` in the constructor, and no `delete` in the destructor. just make it an empty destructor.

Comment: Cool, that's what I did. On the other hand I am getting a whole new list of errors.

Comment: @A.S.H

    Graph Graph::getTranspose()
{
 Graph g(V);
 for (int v = 0; v < V; v++)
 {
  // Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex
  list<int>::iterator i;
  for (i = adj[v].begin(); i != adj[v].end(); ++i)
  {
   g.adj[*i].push_back(v);
   (g.in[v])++;
  }
 }
 return g;
}

Comment: I apologize for the format, I am still new to stack overflow so I am not sure how to properly format the code in a comment, but I am getting an error message: 'no operator "=" matches these operands' at places like this in my code...

// Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex
 list<int>::iterator i;
 for (i = adj[v].begin(); i != adj[v].end(); ++i)
  if (!visited[*i])
   DFSUtil(*i, visited);

Comment: Simply remove the declaration (  `list<int>::iterator i;`  ), and write your loop like this: 
`for (auto i = adj[v].begin(); i != adj[v].end(); ++i)`

Comment: besides, in the constructor, `int adj.Resize(V);` remove the `int`.

Comment: Also, your DFSUtil function looks to me like an infinite recursion. @ferret7DD

Comment: @A.S.H I added the int because I got an error saying the expression must have a class type

Comment: @A.S.H the DFSUtil function should stop once all adjacent vertices have been visited for a particular vertex

Comment: `vector<list<int>> *adj;` ---> `vector<list<int>> adj;`  (no `*`), and remove that `int`.

Comment: @A.S.H I was getting a vector<bool> to bool conversion error before in the void DFSUtil function

Is this the proper way to fix it?
Original:

Comment: Original: void Graph::DFSUtil(int v, bool visited[ ])
Updated: void Graph::DFSUtil(int v, vector<bool> visited())

Comment: @ferret7DD try my code in the edit section. p.s.: good to think of this change, but it should be by reference (`void Graph::DFSUtil(int v, vector<bool>& visited)`

Comment: btw you dont need V anymore, you can get it from `adj.size()`, the size of the adjacency matrix...

Comment: Okay so before I ran the edit code I had 8 errors, now I have 36. There must be something that I am doing wrong in the rest of my code that is not matching up with the edits. @A.S.H Can I post my entire code before the edit? Maybe that would help.

Comment: The number of errors doesnt count. What is the first error?

Comment: @A.S.H

Error (active)  no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=std::list<int, std::allocator<int>>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::list<int, std::allocator<int>>>]" matches the argument list

At this line:
// function to add an edge to graph
 void addEdge(int v, int w) { adj[v].push_back(w);  (in[w])++; }

Comment: hmm.. I also forgot to remove that `*` in the declaration of `adj`... corrected. next

Comment: class "std::vector<std::list<int, std::allocator<int>>, std::allocator<std::list<int, std::allocator<int>>>>" has no member "Resize"

which is expected because I do not know where to put such function definition or how to wrtie it rather

Error occurs here:
Graph::Graph(int V)
{
 adj.Resize(V);
 in.Resize(V, 0);
}

Comment: @A.S.H because I forgot to tag you in the last comment

Comment: Well, this new version compiles for sure. I compiled it successfully, You may have other errors in the rest of the code, but this part is ok now.

Comment: You still have to define the function isSC() I think.

Comment: @A.S.H please see my edit to the original post, I have put the remaining code and that is where most of the errors lie.

Comment: Well, all should compile now. If so, it will be time to use the debugger and take it to a good end :)

Comment: Does it compile all now?

Comment: @A.S.H it is much better now! I just realized the get Transpose function definition was missing

// Function that returns reverse (or transpose) of this graph
// This function is needed in isSC()
Graph Graph::getTranspose()
{
 Graph g(V);
 for (int v = 0; v < V; v++)
 {
  // Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex
  //list<int>::iterator i;
  for (auto i = adj[v].begin(); i != adj[v].end(); ++i)
  {
   g.adj[*i].push_back(v);
   (g.in[v])++;
  }
 }
 return g;
}

When I entered it in I got an error because the argument V is undefined

Comment: Yes it was missing. I added it. Anyway, as I told you before, we removed the `V` data member from the graph class, because it is not needed. We can use `adj.size()` to replace it. @ferret7DD

Comment: Ah yes I remember you saying that. @A.S.H It works perfectly now! I just have one more thing that I would really appreciate your help on if you can. I just wanted to say thank you so much because you've been helping me with my program for a few hours now.

Comment: Go ahead, what is it?

Comment: @A.S.H I want to generate random graphs to test the methods instead of predetermined graphs as I currently have. I will place the code in the original post section.

Comment: @ferret7DD You should test your code first on a few **small** graphs that you draw on your own. Only then you should think of the next step, and it would be really worth another question on SO.

Comment: @A.S.H I have already tested it on one small graph. I am unsure on how to do more than one within one execution.

Comment: In your main, you can construct as many graphs as you want, name them g1, g2, etc.. and test on all of them.

Comment: @A.S.H I tried to make an object but it was outputting an error saying that no such default constructor exists for class "Graph" 

 Graph Graph1;
 Graph1 g(5);
 g.addEdge(1, 0);
 g.addEdge(0, 2);
 g.addEdge(2, 1);
 g.addEdge(0, 3);
 g.addEdge(3, 4);
 g.addEdge(4, 0);

Comment: `Graph Graph1; Graph1 g(5);` ---> `Graph g(5);`

Comment: I was able to fix it!

Comment: Now the numbers that I arbitrarily entered as arguments into Graph g(5) are fairly low. Does it have anything to do with the fact that there are 5 vertices? I know that the weight can be any positive integer. But for the v parameter in addEdge(v,w) can it be any integer? @A.S.H

Comment: No. Your graph, as defined, is NOT weighted. v and w are vertices and you create an unweighted edge between them. v and w must be less that 5, or any size that you specify in the constructor.

Comment: @A.S.H I'm so sorry I had read something wrong. Yes it would not make sense for it to be weighted since a Euler circuit is not particularly interested in the weight of the edges. But, thank you for the clarification!

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf

Comment: "C++ does not support arrays with non-constant size". No, It does support them. I use them all the time. Although it gives a warning, It works. Tested on C++14, C++17, C++20.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
bool visited[V];
```

which standard C++ does not support, write e.g.

```
std::vector<bool> visited(V);
```

You have to include the `<vector>` header to use `std::vector`.